# behat 3 mink testing redirection

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

In symfony 3 controller file I have function:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/user/registration", name="post_registration")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function postRegistration()
    {
        $post = $this->getAllPost();

        $this->curl = $this->get('ApiClient');

        $responseArray = $this->curl->post(
            $this->container->getParameter('api_url') . '/users',
            $post
        );

        if (isset($responseArray['api_key'])) {
            return $this->redirectResponseWithCookie($responseArray['api_key']);
        } else {

            return $this->render(
                static::REGISTRATION_TEMPLATE,
                ['errors' => $responseArray['errors']]
            );
        }
    }
```

In one part it calls function

```
redirectResponseWithCookie()
```

which should redirect the page.

I want to test redirection header - does it have the right Location value.

I have function in UserRegistrationContext class

```
class UserRegistrationContext extends BaseContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext 
{

/**
 * @When I register successfully into the system
 * @return null
 */
public function iRegisterSuccessfullyIntoTheSystem()
{

    $this->canIntercept();
    $this->session->getDriver()->getClient()->followRedirects(false);

    // Enters his data
    // Posts to www.notification.guru .
    $this->session->getDriver()->getClient()
        ->request('POST', $this->baseUrl . '/user/registration', $this->getFormArray());

    echo 'test';

}
}
```

BaseContext class just has some helper functions,  its contructor inits session:

```
$driver = new GoutteDriver();
$this->session = new Session($driver);
```

this part might be wrong:

```
$this->session->getDriver()->getClient()->followRedirects(false);
```

I just took code from behat 2.5 and tried to adjust to work it with behat 3, but not sure if its correct, but at least does not throw error.

It should stop redirect, so then I could get a response header with

```
getResponseHeaders()
```

But the problem is that it tries to redirect, and code fails, because real site is not lauched yet where it redirects. And also I would not be able to test headers I guess after real redirection.

So the redirection has to be stopped I guess.

How to do that? I cannot find info.

Test fails at line

```
$this->session->getDriver()->getClient()
        ->request('POST', $this->baseUrl . '/user/registration', $this->getFormArray());
```

Comment: Actually I see there is no mistake in that code, I did not see well in console after running a test.

Answer (score 1):

So code in my question is not wrong, as I said in comment - I did not see well in console. Often happens that when I post to SO, I do not even finish writing the question, just from writing the details to others I see the answer.

```
$this->session->getDriver()->getClient()->followRedirects(false);
```

works well.

So to finish how to check - make function something like this and call it:

```
/**
 * @param Behat\Mink\Session $session - mink session
 * @throws \Exception
 * @return null
 */
public function isLoggedIntoApi($session)
{
    $headers = $session->getResponseHeaders();

    if ($headers['Location'][0] != $this->appUrl) {
        throw new \Exception(
            'User is not redirected to ' . $this->appUrl
        );
    }
}
```